# How to change bullet color in whole presentation ppt vba

Tags: vba, bullet

trying to change the color of different bullets across a presentation. Bullets have different shapes. Always the error code -2147024809 appears.

Do you see what should be changed? Thank you very much for any help!

---

Sub ReplacebulletColors()

```
Dim lFindColor As Long
Dim lReplaceColor As Long
Dim oSl As Slide
Dim oSh As Shape
Dim x As Long

lFindColor = RGB(1, 98, 155)
lReplaceColor = RGB(192, 0, 0)

For Each oSl In ActivePresentation.Slides
    For Each oSh In oSl.Shapes
        With oSh

            If .TextFrame.TextRange.ParagraphFormat.Bullet.Font.Color.RGB = lFindColor Then
                   .TextFrame.TextRange.ParagraphFormat.Bullet.Font.Color.RGB = lReplaceColor
            End If

        End With
    Next
Next
```

End Sub

Comment: You are assuming that the shape has a textframe property - it may not. Quick (and dirty) fix  would be to add On Error Goto Whoops  after With Osh and then Whoops: after the End If so it just skips them

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply, how can I know what type of property the shape has?

Comment: you'd need to use TypeOf to return the type of the shape and then a select case to only run the code against the appropriate types

Comment: Hi - was this ever resolved? Having the same problem.